# Why my commit's come from signed out github acc? How to log out completely?

Tags: windows, git, github

I am using windows 10 pro.

I need to make commits from my friends github acc, so I remove github credential from credential manager, when I log in with my friend's account, but what I get is permission to push to his repository, it still pushes from my account.

So how do I log out my user and login with new user?

[image]

removing git:https://github.com, doesn't help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

apparently you need to do

```
 git config  user.name "example"
 git config  user.email "example@example.com"
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for these commands?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't care about GitHub accounts. Commits are signed with name and email address provided in the configuration.

Global configuration can be changed using the `git config` command:

```
git config --global user.name "My Name"
git config --global user.email "someone@example.com"
```

Removing `--global` will set these for a single repository only.